# angularJS - my directive link is not called

Tags: angularjs, angular-directive

I am creating new directive in angular app. my directive link is not called for some reason. any one please help me here?

my directive : `<data-grid data=slideView.pages ></data-grid>`

my code :

```
"use strict";

( function() {

var dataGridMaker = function( ) {

    return {
        scope: true, 
        replace: true,
        template:"<h1>Testing</h1>",
        link: function( ) {
            console.log(" Hi there!!");//not calling
        }
    }

}

angular.module( "gridDataApp.directives", [] )
.directive( "dataGrid", dataGridMaker );

} ( ));
```

Comment: If I call the function like `dataGridMaker()` then the function called, but still the `link` method is not calling out.

Comment: the only issue is about link function or with whole directive itself? I mean is your template getting loaded?

Comment: No, template too not loading

Comment: Sounds silly just out of curiosity, you have included your file in some of your page e.g. index.html?

Comment: thats what when i call my function it works like above said `dataGridMaker()`

Comment: Can you post your code where you have application and the HTML part where you are calling your directive?

Comment: here is live demo : `https://plnkr.co/edit/CU5x1kuZrqBIArYVl5oW?p=preview`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

your directive won't be recognized because HTML5 has `datagrid` element already. try change its name to another.

```js
"use strict";

( function() {

var dataGridMaker = function( ) {

    return {
        scope: true, 
        replace: true,
        template:"<h1>Testing</h1>",
        link: function( ) {
            console.log(" Hi there!!");//not calling
        }
    }

}

angular.module( "gridDataApp.directives", [] )
.directive( "sampleGrid", dataGridMaker );

} ( ));
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.4/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="gridDataApp.directives">
  <div sample-grid></div>
</div>
```

Comment: you are correct. still can you have a look at here : https://plnkr.co/edit/CU5x1kuZrqBIArYVl5oW?p=preview`

Comment: @user2024080 change `angular.module("app.directives")` to `angular.module("app.directives", [])`